# Thinking Sphinx and lack of updated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cluster-computing, thinking-sphinx

We are running thinking sphinx on a utility instance in our server cluster.  It is rerunning the index every minute.  But, if you make a change to a record, it disappears from search results until the index is updated (up to 1 minute).

Is Thinking Sphinx only returning rows that have updated_at times that less than their last index?

If so, how can I get db changes to update the TS on the utility instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of re-indexing every minute try using the **Delayed Deltas** approach. It is designed to tide over your search results until you fully re-index.

See:

http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/deltas.html

**Update:**

Looks like the team at sphinx is trying to solve these problems with real-time indexes:

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#rt-indexes

Comment: We ended up turning off delta indexes and just reindex every little while.

Comment: Thinking sphinx definitely a lot simpler without delta indexes. You don't have to manage all these dependent background processes.

Comment: The problem we were running into was with our 4 server cluster.  2 app servers, 1 db and another utility instance which was running sphinx.  Utility wasn't getting notified when deltas occured.  Thanks for the help.